# How to show that $\frac{1}{w-z} = \frac{1}{w-a} + \frac{z-a}{(w-a)^2} + ... $, $w,z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

In the book of *The theory of Functions* by Titchmarsh, at page 83, in the proof of the fact that analytic functions can be expressed as power series, it is stated that

$$\frac{1}{w-z} = \frac{1}{w-a} + \frac{z-a}{(w-a)^2} + \dots \frac{(z-a)^n}{(w-a)^{n+1}} \dots   ,$$
where $w$ is on the circle $\Gamma$ with centre $a$ and radius $\sigma < \delta$, where $|z-a| < \delta$ .

However, I cannot see how the RHS is equal to LHS ? I mean this is basically the Taylor's theorem for complex functions, but this is what we are trying to show in here, so it is confusing.

Comment: I think it is not clear *at all* how the series continues: will it be $\;z-a\;$ all the time in the numerators, or perhaps $\;(z-a)^k\;$ ...?

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for pointing out. I have edited.

Comment: I'm sure Titchmarsh says $\Bbb C$, not $\Bbb C^n$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes of course. It is just a typo because of my shortcuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}\frac1{w-a}+\frac{z-a}{(w-a)^2}+\frac{(z-a)^2}{(w-a)^3}+\cdots&=\frac1{w-a}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{z-a}{w-a}\right)^n\\&=\frac{\frac1{w-a}}{1-\frac{z-a}{w-a}}\\&=\frac1{w-a-z+a}\\&=\frac1{w-z}.\end{align}

Comment: I was writing down exactly the same answer! It is a very nice idea showing that this simply a geometric series multiplied by a constant term.

Comment: Sir, if you were not answering questions on this site, I don't know how bad my Mathematics education would be. Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 4):

Hint. We have that
$$\frac{1}{w-z}=\frac{1}{w-a-(z-a)}=\frac{1}{w-a}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{z-a}{w-a}}.$$
Now consider the case when $\left|\frac{z-a}{w-a}\right|<1$ and recall the main properties of the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: Well, that is nice. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have $S=\frac 1p+\frac {q}{p^2}+\frac {q^2}{p^3}+\dots$ and we multiply by $\frac pq$ then $$\frac pq S=\frac 1q+\frac 1p+\frac q{p^2}+\dots=\frac 1q+S$$ so that $$S=\frac 1{p-q}$$

Now apply with $p=w-a, q=z-a, p-q=w-z$

We are looking at simple geometric progression - but this technique of multiplying or dividing by the common ratio can help to get the calculations right. Also, even with quite simple expressions in the terms, using $p$ and $q$ here to express the shape of the expression saves some algebra, and I find it helps to reduce mistakes.

Obviously, in the context, attention also needs to be given to the conditions for convergence.